# How to do a HTTP DELETE request with Python requests module without "Content-Length: 0"?

Tags: python, python-requests, http-delete, content-length, http-content-length

I am doing a HTTP DELETE with Python requests module, but I am facing a problem in my application because of the "Content-Length: 0". Is there a way to deal with this? Is possible to remove the "Content-Length: 0"? What do you suggest?

The problem is that the server application does not accept "Content-Length", neither payload. This way, my request should not have this information.

The request I am doing:

```
headers = {'X-Auth-Token': token}
r = requests.delete(DELETE_URL, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Would you better explain the problem?  Client side or server side?

Comment: What's wrong with "Content-Length: 0"?

Comment: @wim , I am doing a DELETE request to a server that does not accept content-length. So, I have to remove this information in my request.

I am using this: 
r = requests.delete(DELETE_URL, headers=headers) 
#headers have just the x-auth-token header...

Is there a more direct way to remove the "Content-Length" besides the example marked below as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can remove the header manually like in [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#prepared-requests)

example:

```
from requests import Request, Session

s = Session()

req = Request('DELETE', url)
prepped = req.prepare()
del prepped.headers['Content-Length']
resp = s.send(prepped)
print(resp.status_code)
```